# Single Stepping with Google Sheets Debugger

Tags: google-sheets-macros

I have watched a few videos and read as many web pages about how to debug my Google Sheets Macro. Oddly, I can't get this ridiculously simple macro to work. It just takes the values in column A and sorts them to send duplicate values to the end. When I try to debug the macro using step into, the steps don't seem to actually do anything until I execute the last statement. I see the same problem with the debugger with an even simpler macro that does work. Nothing happens until I step into the last step. BTW, I have written and debugged much more complicated Excel VBA scripts with no problems like I am having with Google scripts. I am trying to migrate to Google sheets due to Excel being beyond bloatware.

```
function EliminateDuplicates() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:A20').activate()
  .sort({column: 1, ascending: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('B2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=A2=A1');
  spreadsheet.getRange('B2:B20').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('B1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('FALSE');
  spreadsheet.getRange('B1:B20').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B1:B20').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:B20').activate()
  .sort({column: 2, ascending: true});
};
```

Comment: A key difference between Google Sheets and Excel is that Excel runs on your machine. Because Google Sheets runs that script invocation on a server somewhere, it caches and internally optimizes function calls/steps that utilize Google APIs and interfaces. "Pure" JavaScript calls will be individually stepped in the debugger. The reason you see no output until the final call is that this caching is occurring. You can force a buffer flush by calling `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't copyTo(... PASTE\_VALUES) work in the middle of a macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50192942/why-doesnt-copyto-paste-values-work-in-the-middle-of-a-macro)

Comment: Yes, that did it. Thank you. I thought that the cache might be a problem but didn't quite know what to do about it.